# Multi module vaadin applicationproblem

Tags: java, maven, jetty, vaadin

I begin to work with *Vaadin* framework and *Maven* and I face up some trouble.
I had an application which works with *Vaadin* and *Maven*. I tried to divide this application in two sub-modules, one with my business method (compiled in Jar) and one with my *Vaadin* UI.

So my project is the following:

> vaadin-maven
>
> > vaadin-maven-biz (business code)
> >     vaadub-maven-web (with vaadin code)

In my web pom, I add my business app as a dependency.

When I run maven package on my parent project, everything is ok, build success for both project, but if i try to run my webapp on jetty with `jetty:run` I had the following problem.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Vaadin Web Application 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.13.v20130916:run (default-cli) @ vaadin-maven-web >>>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE<br>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.263s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 07 17:08:46 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/102M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project vaadin-maven-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project example.vaadin-maven:vaadin-maven-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for (all my dependies are list there):
Failed to read artifact descriptor for example.vaadin-maven:vaadin-maven-biz:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find example.vaadin-maven:vaadin-maven:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I search a lot on internet and tried some solution but nothing works.
Does anybody could help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Jetty has problem with finding maven submodules. Try [this](http://blog.oio.de/2012/09/25/dynamic-reloading-of-vaadin-multi-module-applications-with-maven-and-eclipse-pt-ii/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your local repo contains wrong artifacts. This can happen when you set up a new project and do some renaming/reversioning on the way. You can try to delete the example/vaadin stuff in ~/.m2/repository and perform `mvn clean install` once again.